# What is a two phased commit and how to implement it in Spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I was able to find theoretical answers about "what is two phased commit?" but no good article or page about the way to implement it in Spring.

Especially, if you have Spring + Hibernate in your application then how to implement two phased commit?

Comment: I guess you should use XA awared transactions and datasources

Comment: Thanks Angelo...please can you share an example?...

Comment: Now I can't but maybe here you can find some help https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html

Comment: Thanks again Angelo...i will go through the link shared by you...